# Foreach iteration not iterating through textboxes

Tags: c#, foreach, textbox, iteration

I have made a method to check all of my textboxes and tell me if any are empty. When I debug it and follow through the code it just completely skips over the foreach loop.

Here is my code:

```
private bool checkSolved()
{
    bool isSolved = true; //Solve Variable
    foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) //Iterates through all textboxes
    {
       if (tb.Text == null) //Checks to see if one of them is null
       {
          isSolved = false; //Sets bool to false
       }
    }
    return isSolved; //Returns bool
}
```

Comment: Check the value of this and this.Controls to see if they are what you are expecting, and whether this.Controls does indeed have any TextBox controls in.

Comment: It could appear, that all `Controls` are not of type `TextBox`. When debugging log the types of `Controls` like: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, this.Controls.Select(c => c.GetType().Name + " : " + typeof(TextBox).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType()))));` to check what types are there and whether they are assignable to `TextBox` type

Comment: probably there is no `TextBox` in the `Controls`, because `OfType` has filtered the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBox.Text` will never be null. You need to compare it against `Empty`. Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
{

}
```

If it doesn't execute the loop at all then your `Controls` collection doesn't have any `TextBox` in it.

**Edit1:** Some hints to debug:

If you can't manage to get this work, most probably your Textboxes will not be parented by `this`(your control here). It will have been added to some other parent instead. It could be `Panel` or `GroupBox` etc. In that case accessing `this.Controls` is not useful you need to access `respectiveParent.Controls` collection. You do it [like this recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405350/2530848).

Comment: That is correct, but not an answer to the question why the `foreach` loop was skipped. You should write this as a comment.

Comment: @chris Of course, this is an answer. What makes you think this should be a comment?

Comment: Because OP asked about why `forach` block doesn't execute at least once. You happily downvoted other answers while providing incorrect answer.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Does this answers the question? *If it doesn't execute the loop at all then your Controls collection doesn't have any TextBox in it.* Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25405107/2530848) means nothing. So I downvoted.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Come on, How this is an incorrect answer? Give justification please? Am happy to delete this.

Comment: ok, that last sentence answers the question, I just skipped it quickly, my mistake. I would put +1 if you'll comment on how OP could verify and diagnose the types in `Controlls` and if they derived from `TextBox`.

Comment: I also skipped the last sentence - so yes, technically it is not an _incorrect_ answer, but certainly not a _better_ answer than mine, which you downvoted

Comment: @IlyaIvanov and chris Updated my answer, I also should admit this is not a best answer, but an answer to the question as it stands. If OP provides more info I'll be happy to help more.

Comment: See my answer, this is not this.Control it is recursive, and all child of control will check...

Answer (score 2):

You need a recursive search. Also, `TextBox.Text` never returns `null`, the property returns `""` instead. This extension returns all controls of a given type [lazily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildControlsRecursive<T>(this Control root) where T: Control
{
    if (root == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        Control parent = stack.Pop();
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T)
                yield return (T) child;
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Now you can use this code to check if all TextBoxes have text:

```
var textBoxes = this.GetChildControlsRecursive<TextBox>();
bool isSolved = textBoxes.All(txt => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text));
```

Comment: this seems solving two problems, mentioning TextBox.Text never null and the recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static List<T> GetAllControlsInside<T>(Control control)
    {
        List<Control> result = new List<Control>();
        GetAllControlsInside<T>(control, result);
        return result.OfType<T>().ToList();
    }

    private static void GetAllControlsInside<T>(Control control, List<Control> result)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
        {
            result.Add(ctrl);
            if (ctrl.HasChildren && !(ctrl is T))
            {
                GetAllControlsInside<T>(ctrl, result);
            }
        }
    }


private bool checkSolved()
{
    bool isSolved = true; //Solve Variable
    foreach (TextBox tb in GetAllControlsInside<TextBox>(this)) //Iterates through all textboxes
    {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)) //Checks to see if one of them is null
       {
          isSolved = false; //Sets bool to false
       }
    }
    return isSolved; //Returns bool
}
```